# How do I add the value of a token list with braces in LaTeX?

Tags: expl3, best-practices, latex3, token-lists

In my LaTeX3 code, I frequently find myself wanting to add the value of one token list (or other variable) to another but surrounded by braces (a common use case is where I'm constructing a command to be called later on where I need to do some complicated calculations to construct the arguments to it).

I recently had the idea of doing the following:

```
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \tl_put_right_braced:Nn #1#2
{
  \tl_put_right:Nn #1 {{#2}}
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_put_right_braced:Nn {NV}
```

That way, I'm thinking that I exploit the variant stuff which is already embedded in LaTeX3 and don't have to figure out the correct expansions myself.

So, my question is essentially "Is this okay?" with a side order of "Is there a better way?" (and an optional dessert of "What should I call this function?").

Comment: I see almost no problem in the code. However, the name should not begin with `\tl_`, which is reserved to the kernel. You should use `\cs_new_protected:Npn`; I see no real reason for `nopar`, but several for `protected`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks - those are useful comments. Any recommendations for the name? It's something I'd use in several of my packages so most obvious would be a little `utils` module that each included.

Comment: The prefix should be unique for package/author. Maybe you can use `asutils` for general purpose functions to be used in several packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function that performs assignments should be `protected`. I see no real reason for using `nopar`, even less if this is has to be a general purpose utility.

If you have several general purpose utilities, you should have a package `asutils` for which you can define (and register) a prefix such as `asutils`. Now your function would be

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \asutils_tl_put_right_braced:Nn
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn #1 { { #2 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \asutils_tl_put_right_braced:Nn { NV, cV, cv, Nx, cx }
```

Whether the companion `gput` is needed, you're the judge.

The prefix `tl` is reserved for the kernel and should not be used by anyone else.