# LaTeX3 "V" expansion in braces

Tags: expansion, latex3

How do I set the value of a variable such that its content is the value from another variable surrounded in curly braces?

For example, if `\l_tmpa_tl` is `\alpha`, how should I control expansion so that `\l_tmpb_tl` is `{\alpha}`?

What if I want `\l_tmpb_tl` to be `{{\alpha}}`?

Comment: You might find this useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/572885/86

Comment: Similar question →[expl3 - LaTeX3 - Expand nested argument - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640324/latex3-expand-nested-argument)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `\exp_not:V` seems to do what you're looking for, although there may be a more elegant way.

Running this:

```tex
\nonstopmode
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \somemacro
\tl_set:Nn \somemacro { some~content }

\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \somemacro }
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl {{{ \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl }}}

\ShowCommand \l_tmpa_tl
\ShowCommand \l_tmpb_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff

\csname @@end\endcsname
```

gives this output:

```tex
> \l_tmpa_tl=macro:
->\somemacro .
<argument> \l_tmpa_tl 
                      
l.10 \ShowCommand \l_tmpa_tl
                            

> \l_tmpb_tl=macro:
->{{\somemacro }}.
<argument> \l_tmpb_tl 
                      
l.11 \ShowCommand \l_tmpb_tl
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I am not aware of the existence of `\exp_not:V`. It is so difficult to not miss something in the LaTeX3 documentation!

Comment: I think this is the most elegant solution :)